# Android - ViewPager.PageTransformer doesn't exist

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm following this tutorial **Using ViewPager for Screen Slides** http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
but I've problem.
In other words, I want to implement ViewPager.PageTransform but this interface doesn't exist, like image shows.
[image]

I put v13 support library and minTarget is 14.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project? Also, try to finish the word and then press `Ctrl + Shift + O` to organize your imports.

Comment: yes, I tried. Now I try Ctrl + Shift + O

Comment: Also Ctrl + Shift + O doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are on the 19.0.1 version of the Android Support package, as the following works for me in a scrap project that I just created:

```
package com.example.viewpagertransformtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager pager=new ViewPager(this);

    pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {

      @Override
      public void transformPage(View arg0, float arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am on the 19.0.1 version! however, the problem is that ViewPager v4 is different in viewpager v13. in v13 i can't use `pager.setPageTransformer()`: IDE says me that it doesn't exist

Comment: @hooloovoo: The above code is from a project that uses the `-v13` JAR. Now, it took a bit of fussing to get Eclipse to be happy. Try removing both `-v4` and `-v13` JARs from the project. Then add in `-v4`, get it compiling cleanly, then remove `-v4` and replace it with `-v13`.

Comment: I'm happy for you beacuse for me anything is changed! I'm sorry for my answare but I'm tired.

Answer (score 0):

Just type "PageTransformer" rather than "ViewPager." Then try Ctrl + Shift + O :)