# Conflict with Support Library v4 and Support Library v13 in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

good morning.
I'm following thi guide from Android Developers **Using ViewPager for Screen Slides** http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
I need Support library v4 and support library v13, but when I build project in Android Studio I've this response

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/home/angelo/Tool/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/dx --dex --output /home/angelo/AndroidStudioPojects/Example/app/build/libs/app-debug.dex /home/angelo/AndroidStudioPojects/Example/app/build/classes/debug /home/angelo/AndroidStudioPojects/Example/app/build/dependency-cache/debug /home/angelo/AndroidStudioPojects/Example/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v13-d5a7cbb57982899175e7a62be2ac2c67.jar /home/angelo/AndroidStudioPojects/Example/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v4-04300e1af199015053fed2602ec8d39c.jar
  Error Code:
2
  Output:

  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:593)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:551)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:532)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:169)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:187)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I understand it's a problem due to conflicts of library, but if I remove one of this I can't use some class or method.
I necessarily need both.

Comment: Since `-v13` contains everything in `-v4`, I fail to see why you think that you "necessarily need both". The sample project you cite only uses `-v13`. Why do you think that you need both?

Comment: yes I know, but if I remove v4 I can't use ViewPager.setPageTransformer() method: it's in v4, but not in v13.

Comment: more precisely this ask is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713230/android-viewpager-pagetransformer-doesnt-exist 
If I remove -v4 I have the situation of second ask, if I remove -v13 I can't use FragmentStatePagerAdapter Interface.
Also, sample code imports both library.

Comment: Try this.
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069006/754485][1]
Should be that answer, worked for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069006/754485

Answer (score 1):

Yo don't need both libraries, just add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.1'
```

In your **build.gradle** and you'll be fine because support-v13 contains support-v4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ccouldn't build the project because of this project, fortunately I am not using the support library in my project so I commented the support library instance on the build.gradle file, then I compiled the project and everything want fine.

Finally, I uncommented that line again and build the project and the issue was gone. That problem is related with including support library twice. Hope this works for you.